# How to apply isPointInPath() to multiple path

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am currently testing whether the point is within multiple path. For instance,

```
const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
const ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(278, 110)
ctx.lineTo(390, 152)
ctx.lineTo(305, 255)
ctx.lineTo(221, 213)
ctx.closePath();

if (ctx.isPointInPath(284, 150)) {
  console.log('Inside Path!')
};
```

However, it is working wrongly because the case the ctx.isPointInPath(284, 150) does not work and console.log('Inside Path!') inside if sentence does not run. But the point is inside of lines.

Where should I improve this ?

Comment: Can you specify the x and y values for which the function is returning the wrong result?

Comment: Sorry for my question. I edited it more precisely.

Comment: Two things: 1) that is not an array 2) it is being console logged as inside path. What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I mean the point inside paths should be detected by isPointInPath but my code above is not working. But the point at (284, 150) is in the area drawn by lineTo. Therefore I am confusing.

Comment: As Justin said, the code inside the if block is executed and gets logged to the console. Which means the point (284, 150) is within the bounds of the specified path, and everything is working as expected. Are you sure you've pasted the correct code?

Comment: No. I mean, console.log('Inside Path!') is not shown in this code.

Comment: Yes it is shown. I pasted your code exactly as written and it does get console logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have presented.

Why you code does not output to the console can not be deduced from the information provided. The example below is a copy of your code (slightly modified) and works as expected.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo( 78, 10);
ctx.lineTo(190, 52);
ctx.lineTo(105, 149);
ctx.lineTo( 21, 113);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
const p = {x: 84, y: 50};
ctx.isPointInPath(p.x, p.y) && console.log('Inside Path!');
ctx.fillRect(p.x-4, p.y, 9, 1);
ctx.fillRect(p.x, p.y-4, 1, 9);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```